# How to add observers to an NSManagedObject?

Tags: cocoa, observer-pattern, key-value-observing, nsmanagedobject, addobserver

What is the preferred approach to registering observers on an `NSManagedObject` (since Core Data "'owns' the lifecycle" of managed objects)?

Am I correct that the way to do this is to listen for `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange-Notification` and call `addObserver:...` for `NSInsertedObjectsKey` and `removeObserver:...` for `NSDeletedObjectsKey`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to observe MOs throughout their lifecycles, add observers when they come into existence, with `awakeFromInsert` and `awakeFromFetch`.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, you're correct. Observing the MOs directly will lead to trouble, for reasons you have already posted in your question (within the parentheses).

Comment: Actually, I think what I suggested above is wrong. I think the place to add observers is `awakeFromInsert` and `awakeFromFetch`. (Removing them is unnecessary.)

Comment: What actually is it that you want to do? If you want to do something when the MO is created, then sure, awakeFromInsert and awakeFromFetch are your friends. But if you want to observe changes to some random MOs, the above I think is correct. Depends on what you're after.

Comment: I want to observe instances of some MOs throughout their lifecycles, so if I add observers when they come into existence (with `awakeFromInsert` and `awakeFromFetch`), I should be fine.